# Ordering a group by in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

Hi I am sorry if this has been asked somewhere else but I cant seem to find any answers for this.. or non that I can get to work. 
I have a table with a list of actions for each user. I am trying to get every users last action. I am wanting to group by user and order by the time. what this seems to be doing is returning the first action and ordering that.

Here is the query I am using:

```
SELECT 
     userid, 
     time
FROM
     useractions
GROUP BY 
     userid
ORDER BY 
     time
```

Any help would be much apreciated. Sorry if this turns out to be a stupid question. Thanks

Comment: Is that mysql? sql server?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek As far as I know every DB other than MySQL would throw  a message about time not being part of an aggregate or group by

Comment: yeah it is a mysql database, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
     userid, 
     max(time)
FROM
     useractions
GROUP BY 
     userid
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That just shows the latest user. I am trying to get the latest per user if that is possible

Comment: the query should get you latest action for each user. Please check if you are not using max on the userid.

Comment: Ahh my bad, I was using order by for some reason, sorry. Thanks for the fast reply!!

Comment: Yeah I tried that a few mins ago and I was getting a message saying I had to wait x mins before I could lol.